# JQuery функция sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
console.log(typeof $('#elementId').sortable); // function
function init_sortable(){
  console.log(typeof $('#elementId').sortable); // undefined
}
init_sortable();
```

В чем может быть дело? Скажите хоть варианты, а то уже весь код перерыл и понять не могу ничего

Comment: попробуй `.sortable()`

Comment: Да нет, я когда юзать начинаю внутри функции он пишет is not a funcion, а в глобальной области нормально все

Comment: нужно больше кода... больше информации, где и какие скрипты подключаются например. может что-то обернуто в `$(function{}());` ... ибо при текущем раскладе проблема не воспроизводится http://jsfiddle.net/60byu6xv/  ........ а возможно дело подключаемых внешних скриптах и протоколе `https` (совсем магия)

Comment: Оратор выше прав: либо что-то удаляет метод сортировки, либо Вы неверно определили где `undefined` вываливается.